# pygame.error Unsupported image format

Tags: python, image, pygame, exit

running Python 3.3.0 with pygame '1.9.2pre', following a tutorial, new to python, honestly cant see where i've gone wrong, looks the same as on the tutorial, however it is 4 years old. Thanks for help!

I get error - unsupported image format for both. I've tried jpg and png, the version spec says it supports them both.

```
bif ="bg.jpg"
mif ="man.jpg"
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1100,750),0,32)
background = pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
mouse_c = pygame.image.load(mif).convert_alpha()


Running = True

while Running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            Running = False
            sys.exit()
            break

    screen.blit(background,(0,0))

    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x -= mouse_r.get_width()/2
    y -= mouse_r.get_height()/2

    screen.blit(mouse_r,(x,y))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the pygame window is not shutting due to the error in your code. You can exit the python shell to exit the pygame window, but the error is the main issue here.

If you're importing images like so, make sure the images are in the same folder or location as your .py file
I don't understand where you got mouse_r out of.

Try this:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *



pygame.init()



screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1100,750),0,32)

background = pygame.image.load("bg.jpg").convert()
mouse_c = pygame.image.load("man.jpg").convert_alpha()

Running = True

while Running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            Running = False
            sys.exit()
            break

    screen.blit(background,(0,0))

    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x -= screen.get_width()/2
    y -= screen.get_height()/2

    screen.blit(mouse_c,(x,y))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I can recommend 2 options for the moment. Remove pygame altogether and re-install using this link here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame ... where you can get pygame for python 3.3.0 ... Open your images in an image editor (xnView) and save as a bmp image type, so you can then load into pygame with no hassle

Comment: With the bmp images? If your run python shell, `import pygame`, and run the function   `pygame.image.get_extended()` what number does it return?

Comment: That should be correct. A return value of 1 states that you should be able to load all image formats. I'm afraid I don't what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you've used the wrong variable name here:

```
x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
x -= mouse_r.get_width()/2
y -= mouse_r.get_height()/2

screen.blit(mouse_r,(x,y))
```

I've watched the [same tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kls88vnGC_Y) before and it seems that `mouse_r` should be `mouse_c`.

Edit:

Try using the full directory path name while loading the images:

```
import os
bif = os.getcwd() + "\\bg.jpg"
mif = os.getcwd() + "\\man.jpg"
```

Comment: It seems the real issue here is that pygame won't support the jpeg format, as the code in my answer did not work either. Pygame documentation states that pygame will only support bmp image types if not built with full image support. But this is not a problem with me or many others. The question is why?